# How to update rescue partition on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, rescue, software-updates

I have a Fedora 24 installation, where one of the items on the boot menu is:

```
Fedora 19 Rescue ...
```

How do I update that so I have the latest Fedora rescue partition?  Does it even matter?

I suspect that I initially installed Fedora 19 and then have upgraded multiple times since then.  Maybe the upgrade process upgraded the main partition but not the rescue partition, or something; I don't know.

Comment: Hmmm.....does it really matter?  I generally use the rescue mode to do things like fsck the root, change the root password, or change a broken startup script. These type of operations generally do not require the latest version.  In fact, I have also used a DVD with a totally different Linux distribution and version to make these type of changes.

Comment: @mdpc, I don't know!  Good question.  If it doesn't matter, that'd be useful to know, too.  (For instance, might updates to LVM or raid or similar software require you to use the newest rescue mode, or is that unlikely?)